# How to know when a sum can be replaced by an integral?

Tags: integration, summation

I am a chemist reading a bit of physics. I know very little of maths as you will see.
Here we have a sum:

$$Q=\Large\sum_{x=1}^\infty x e^{-\beta E_x}$$
where $\beta$ is a constant.

**Question**

How can understand mathematically if the sum can be replaced by an integral?

Comment: Keep in mind, physicists like to "round off" and "discard insignificantly small numbers" while mathematicians rather keep everything clean and exact. I suspect this being a case where you round things off just to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the comment..But I don't know why that can be done..@vrugtehagel..

Comment: I'm also moderately confused by the summation variable having a subscript $x$. Could you give some context around that? Is it just notation? As I see it now, it seems like $x$ could take on a value (and we could compute $E_2$ for example, using $n_2$), yet $n_x$ being the summation variable means it's defined the same regardless of what $x$ is.

Comment: Need to compare $\Delta E$ with $1/\beta = k_BT$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel No, that's wrong. I will correct that

Comment: [integrals are limits of sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral), so a sum can be approximated by an integral if the distance between the sampling points (here $E_x-E_{x-1}$) is much smaller than the length scale on which the function (here $\exp(-\beta x)$) varies.

Comment: @velutluna Yes, I suppose so, but how that implies sum can be replaced by integral?

Comment: @Wouter thanks. I don't know why it is so..

Comment: maybe some example or demostration would help @Wouter

Comment: @HernanMiraola you've deleted some pretty important parts of the question just now. Your statement isn't true without the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so you can see a summation as an approximation of an integral using bars of width $1$. For example, we could compute the integral of $\sqrt{x}$ from $2$ to $7$ by looking at

[image: graph]

so we could sum $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{6}$ and we'd have a decent approximation of the integral $$\int_2^7\sqrt{x}\text{d}x$$
You see, if the graph is very steep, the difference in the method with the bars and the actual integral gets really big, but if the graph is nearly horizontal, the integral and the bars method (usually called Riemann Sum, by the way) is very small. Basically, your first summation can be converted to an integral because the difference between two neighbouring bars, expressing the steepness of the graph, is very small.

Comment: Nice answer. Don't you have to multiply the values on the sum by the step?

Comment: @HernanMiraola The stepsize is $1$ here.

Comment: @velutluna oh you are right..

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give details of the systems.

I suppose the first one is particle in a one dimensional box, and the $m$ and $L$ are so that
$$\frac{h^2}{8mL^2} \ll \frac{1}{\beta}$$
while in the second system, $h \nu$ is not much smaller than $1/\beta$.

Comment: I edited the post to be clearer

Comment: @HernanMiraola Do you know the equipartition theorem?

Comment: yes I know. And I know it is related to the post..